# How to check null values using kendo template

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi I've a kendo grid like below and I wanted to check null value for column and based on condition I want to display some default number to the column

Here is my sample code.

```
 $("#eCount").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: myModel,
            pageSize: 5
},      
 columns: [
            {
                field: "Count",
                title: "Count",
                template: '# if (Count == "null" ) {#1#} else {#Count#}#'
            }]
});
```

But I'm not getting how to get it done. Any solution?

Comment: I've got the soluion '#if(Count===null) {# 1 #}else{# #=Count# # }# ' it is working for me

Answer (score 50):

You can use Javascripts inline if format

```
#= street2 != null ? street2 : '' #
```

Comment: That works! In a multi-valued address (street1,county, state,country) - how to skip commas beside null values

Comment: you can do an .indexOf(',') to see if the string has a comma in it. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 20):

I found this to be the most usefull:

```
#= typeof street2 == "undefined" || street2 == null ? "" : street2 #
```

The `typeof` check can be useful when adding rows programatically to the grid's datasource and not specifying the value for the `street2` field:

```
grid.dataSource.add({}); //this line will generate an error when you're not using 'typeof' check
```

Also related to your question, for more complex scenarios, I've also found useful to do other checks inside the template using `data.xxx`, like this:

```
# if (data.street2 && data.street2.length) { #
    <span>#: street2 # </span>
# } else { #
    <span>N/A</span>
# } #
```

Comment: If you have a Kendo drop down list column as a custom MVC editor in a Kendo grid and the drop down list is empty, you have to use the 'typeof' check cited. Initially, I was only checking if the value is null, but it's actually undefined. One symptom of this is that you'll get an undefined reference error from jquery on your custom template.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
    ...
    },
    schema: {
        model: {

            myCount: function () {
                return this.get("Count") == null ? 1 : this.get("Count");
            }
        }
    }

<script id="template">
        #=myCount()#
</script>
```

Or you can do this if you are not using a datasource.

```
<script id="template">
    # var count = data.Count || 1; # // Javascript  #   #
    <span>#=count#</span>            // Binding  #=   #
</script>
```